# How to call MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan using Reflection API?

Tags: c#, struct, system.reflection

Let's suppose I have this C# structure:

```
  public struct Test
  {
      public int Code1;
      public int Code2;
  }
```

This code works fine:

```
  var test = new Test { Code1 = 1, Code2 = 2 };
  var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref test, 1));
```

In `bytes`, I will get an array of 8 bytes `(1, 0, 0, 0,  2, 0, 0, 0).`

Now, how can I call the same methods *CreateSpan + AsBytes* using Reflection API instead of a predefined/generic type?

I have tried this for the `CreateSpan` part:

```
  private static object GetBytes(object value)
  {
      var method = typeof(MemoryMarshal).GetMethod(nameof(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan));
      var gmethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(value.GetType());
      var parameters = new object[] { value, 1 };
      return gmethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
  }
```

But on `Invoke` (using the same test instance), it says: `System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'`

PS: I would like to avoid pointers and `unsafe` keyword.

Comment: `Span` cannot be boxed, so this is never going to work with reflection. Can you use a generic function to do everything you need, then invoke that function using reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `Span<T>` using reflection because [it cannot be boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0#remarks) (to prevent stack references escaping).

The only thing you can do is create a generic function that does all you want it to do, then call *that* using reflection.

For example, you could return a `byte[]` array out of a generic function

```cs
private static byte[] GetBytes(object value)
{
    var method = typeof(ThisType).GetMethod("GetByteArray", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var gmethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(value.GetType());
    return (byte[])gmethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });
}

private static byte[] GetByteArray<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    return MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<T>(ref value, 1)).ToArray();
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vmEx4w)